DB2 RESTORE on new server affects database on original server
My question is pretty simple: Can a DB2 RESTORE on one server, affect the server where the backup originated? That is, can the DB2 RESTORE command contact the original server and do "something" because it stores server name and DB credentials in the backup?
I'm using DB2 for Windows, v11.1 on SERVER1 and v11.5 FP9 on SERVER 2. I'm doing this to establish a test-system on a separate server with the production data.
The sequence of events was as following:

I do a DB2 BACKUP on SERVER1
I copy the backup files to SERVER2
I do a DB2 RESTORE on SERVER2

At the EXACT same moment I start the DB2 RESTORE on SERVER2, I start getting the following errors in db2diag on SERVER1:

Password validation for user db2admin failed with rc = -2146500483

I'm quite lost here and have halted the process for now.
One theory I have is that both DB2 installations are residing on the same SAN, and maybe the DB2 RESTORE is so intensive, that it disrupts the operation of the SERVER1 DB2.
Thanks,
/Morten.

You should ask this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com because this question is not about programming, and is therefore off topic for stackoverflow. It may get closed for that reason.
